# Возврат на предыдущую страницу методом PHP в MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Есть страница пользователя user/id, шаблон mvc. На страницу пользователя можно попасть через поиск на сайте, либо через личные контакты, либо введя id в строку браузера. На странице пользователя есть поле отправки ему короткого сообщения. Как сделать так что бы после ввода и отправки этого сообщения отправитель сообщения переправлялся на предыдущую страницу или на главную, если был прямой заход на профиль. Пробовал через $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], но проблема в том что если обновить страницу пользователя, то переадресация идет на саму страницу и вызывает ошибку mvc. Интересует решение только через PHP, в какую сторону вообще 'глядеть'

Comment: При чём здесь ваша архитектура (MVC), и то, как переходить обратно на предыдущую страницу? Если вы про POST запрос на отправку формы, можно отсылать этот запрос через AJAX (event.preventDefault()), и не делать переход туда через form action.

Comment: если не хочется возиться с ajax, то можно вместе на сервер вместе данными формы передать адрес на который нужно вернуться.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас реализована полноценная архитектура MVC-приложения, то у вас должен быть роутинг, то получится что-то подобное и будет работать корректно, вы же можете свою переменную `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` проверять на соответствие текущей странице (код только для примера):

```
    /**
     * @var bool $activeCurPage
     */
    $activeCurPage = preg_match ("/$_SERVER [REQUEST_SCHEME]://$_SERVER [HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER [REQUEST_URI]/", $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);

    if (!$activeCurPage) {
        redirect (createRedirectUrl ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]));
    } else {
        redirect (createRedirectUrl ('/main')); // ну или как там у вас
    }
```